# Add "Available Databases" dropdown to custom toolbar in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, toolbar

I am creating my own custom toolbar in SSMS. I would like to add the "Available Databases" dropdown that is part of the SQL Editor toolbar to my custom toolbar. But I can't figure out how to add it. It does not appear to be in the command list.

Comment: I think you can only have one `Available Databases` dropdown and I don't think you can put it anywhere except the `SQL Editor` toolbar - even if you disable it in that toolbar. You should specify which version of SSMS you're talking about, though.

Comment: In 2008 R2, I used to just drag it from the SQL Editor toolbar onto my own custom toolbar and then reset the SQL Editor toolbar.  This doesn't look possible in 2014, I can't drag anything.  You had to have the Customize dialog open in order to drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've been able to do this (using SSMS 2016) was by playing around with the `.vssettings` file directly. First I had to identify the GUID for the `Available Databases` command by removing it from the `SQL Editor` toolbar and exporting the settings. This added a `<remove Cmd ...>` entry to the settings file. Then I could use that GUID to add it to my custom toolbar as follows:

```
<Category name="Environment_CommandBars" Category="{B9D9C123-B500-4202-B887-57C829CBD08F}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_CommandBars" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
  <CommandBars Version="05072811">
    <DefaultCustomizations/>
    <UserCustomizations>
      <add_group Group="{8D3759E8-C5F6-4C93-B672-43B89D8479A5}:00000202" GroupPri="40000001" Menu="{8D3759E8-C5F6-4C93-B672-43B89D8479A5}:00000602"/>
      <add_toolbar Menu="{8D3759E8-C5F6-4C93-B672-43B89D8479A5}:00000602" Name="Customer Toolbar" MenuType="toolbar"/>
      <modify_toolbar Menu="{8D3759E8-C5F6-4C93-B672-43B89D8479A5}:00000602" Name="Pleomax" Visibility="show" FullScreen="hide" Dock="top" Row="1" FloatRectangle="0,0,45,24" DockRectangle="1,0,45,24"/>
      <add Cmd="{52692960-56BC-4989-B5D3-94C47A513E8D}:00000004" CmdPri="40000001" Group="{8D3759E8-C5F6-4C93-B672-43B89D8479A5}:00000202" GroupPri="40000001" Menu="{8D3759E8-C5F6-4C93-B672-43B89D8479A5}:00000602"/>
    </UserCustomizations>
  </CommandBars>
</Category>
```

The key things to **not** change above are the `Cmd="{...}"` and `CmdPri="..."`. The `Group`, `GroupPri` and `Menu` values should all match whatever is assigned when you create the custom toolbar (and export the settings).

Then when you import the modified settings file, it should have the `Available Databases` drop-down combo box in your customer toolbar!

Comment: This absolutely worked in SSMS 2016! The guid you show above seems to be the universal guid for that box as well. Funny experience I had was after installing 2014 on a clean box and importing my settings from the old box where the 'Available Databases' was on its own line, the clean install somehow merged it into the one command bar. Life was good for a day until I decided to upgrade to 2016. Your answer is much appreciated for us OCD types.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is "Re-install SSMS", unfortunately.